# Assembly $ character semnification

Tags: assembly, masm

I have a difficult exam (for me :D ) and can't find the signification of '$' character. As an example, I have the next code:

```
DATA    SEGMENT
vector  db    00h,10h,20h,30h,40h
        db    50h,60h,70h,80h,90h   
lv      equ   ($ - vector)/TYPE vector
```

Can someone tell me which is the value of lv?

Comment: Which assembly language? It has different meanings in different ASMs.

Comment: This looks like it could be used to denote the current memory offset, but it's just a guess...

Comment: We're working with I8086 processor...and as compiling program we are using MASM, if this helps you :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` contains the address where the current instruction will be.

The value of `lv` will be the number of items in the `vector` data. The expression `($ - vector)` calculates the number of bytes from the `vector` label to the place in the code where the `$` is used, i.e. where `lv` is declared.

The length is divided by the size of the data used in `vector`. If you had ten words instead of bytes, then `lv` would still be 10, as the 20 bytes that it occupies would be divided by 2.

Comment: ah, beat me to it! =D

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure the last part:

`lv      equ   ($ - vector)/TYPE vector`

Should get you the number of elements in the vector array. The entire code is roughly equivalent to the following in C:

```
int vector[10] = {0x00,0x10,0x20,0x30,0x40,0x50,0x60,0x70,0x80,0x90};
int lv = sizeof(vector) / sizeof(vector[0]);
```

Explanation: in MASM, `$` denotes the current memory offset. I.e. you've stuffed the array `vector` into memory, and the memory offset will be right where it ends. Thus, `$ - vector` will subtract the pointer to the array from the current offset, effectively giving you the array's size.

In MASM,

> The TYPE operator returns the size (in bytes) of each element in an array.

(quote from http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Instructions/lecture.html - seems like a good MASM doc, by the way). I.e. it's equivalent to C's `sizeof(vector[0]);`.